# Int* to String in Golang

Tags: go

I need to get the string value of pointer, how can I achieve it?

Something like `&a.String()`

Comment: What does "string value of a pointer" mean in your context? What are you actually trying to accomplish? Can you give an example of input & desired output?

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: Your edit doesn't answer any of my questions, though. What are are you actually trying to do, and what result are you trying to get?

Comment: "Also, it will be time consuming to go through language specs, that's why I posted here." sounds a bit selfish. When you post here, it consumes a lot of time, but it's *other people's* time. If you don't show that you've made an effort to figure out the answer yourself, why should anyone spend their time helping you?

Comment: @Adrian I got the desired result from one of the answers. Anyway, thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `fmt.Sprintf()`:

```
func main() {
    i := 42
    ip := &i
    strValue := fmt.Sprintf("%p", &ip)
    fmt.Println(strValue)
}
```